# I start a win32 process in uwp, and start nodejs in the win32 by System.Diagnostics.Process, But it met some error after package

Tags: c#, uwp

As in the title, I start a win32 process in uwp, and start nodejs in the win32 by System.Diagnostics.Process. I set the StartInfo as follows:

`p=new System.Diagnostics.Process(); p.StartInfo.FileName=System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath+"node.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguements=System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath+"new1.js";`

when I debug in VS 2017, it runs ok.  But when I package it to an appx and run, it seems that it cannot find the new1.js file, however, the node.exe can be found. The error in nodejs is "Error:Cannot find module 'C:\Program'". I really wonder why.

Comment: Your path contains spaces. Wrap them with `"`

Comment: Could you explain in detail please? I don't know what do you mean by spaces in my path.

Comment: I dont know where the space is

Comment: oh, I know what you mean now,thank you so much

Comment: glad to hear that:)

Comment: Apparently the exe, node.exe and new1.js are in the same folder. If you set the Environment.CurrentDirectory to that directory, you can just use the filename (node.exe and new1.js) to locate the files, without having to get their absolute path.

Comment: yeah,you said quite right. I'm just not quite clear about the directories of uwp project

Comment: the CurrentDirectory of a uwp project seems to be C:\Windows\System32, is it right? I dont know if I can control the directory.

Comment: You can print it to a log to examine it. At the entry point of your exe, add this line Environment.CurrentDirectory = Application.StartupPath; then you could just run it like Process.Start(“node.exe”, “new1.js”);

Comment: Was your issue resolved?

Comment: yes，just as vasily.sib said, wrap the path with ""